# In React-native Js files how can we get without folder paths is It possible?

Tags: javascript, react-native

i am developing one sample implemented Project, in this project some js files getting from paths like ./../folder/file.js and some files getting from folders like 'myfile' here second way when will we get like this.
i am confusing this second way any one clarify this .

here i am attached image please check it once image.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have following files

```
app
  /constants
     StringConstants.js
  /utils
     StringHelper.js
```

StringConstants.js

```
export const DONE_BUTTON_LABEL='DONE';
export const CREATE_ALERT= 'Create Email Alert';
export const CREATE= 'CREATE';
export const CANCEL= 'Cancel';
```

StringHelper.js

```
class StringHelper {
   ...
}
export default new StringHelper();
```

How to import? See following examples

```
import StringHelper '../utils/StringHelper';
import * as StringConstants from '../utils/StringConstants';
//You just imported all constants from StringConstants file. Use it as StringConstants.DONE_BUTTON_LABEL or StringConstants.CREATE

import {CREATE_ALERT} StringConstants from '../utils/StringConstants';
//import CREATE_ALERT constant from StringConstants file.
```